# displaying an NSProgressIndicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsprogressindicator

I would like to display an indeterminate `NSProgressIndicator` in my app, but I can't find anything online that tells me explicitly how to do it. Could someone point me to some sort of tutorial or provide me some example code?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgIndic/ProgIndic.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000024i
And What have you tried?

Comment: @Larme well I can't initialize it or subclass it or add it through xib or anything. Also I apologize if its a really obvious mistake, I'm a beginner :)

Comment: Is your question tagged iOS by mistake? That is a OS X control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a progress view (a horizontal bar) you should use [`UIProgressView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you want an indeterminate spinning activity indicator, you can use a [`UIActivityIndicatorView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html). Both of these can be added to a storyboard or NIB, or can be added programmatically in iOS. Both of those two class references include links to samples.

`NSProgressIndicator` is not an iOS control.

Comment: well that would explain why xcode wasn't recognizing NSProgressIndicator.